# discord.py , storing user id and numbers in .json properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**intro**
hello there , iam trying to create a counter/stat system . its stores how many time a user sayed a specific word , and maybe soon more , but for now i just try getting started. i spend the whole sunday with this so far .
i started python 5 days ago , and its the first time i try me in coding , pls explain, be friendly & helpful.

**my problem**
i just can store one word counter per user.
i have problems creating a command to get the stats.

**bot.py :**

```
def load_stats():
    with open('stats.json', 'r') as f:
        stats = json.load(f)
    return stats

def save_stats(stats):
    with open('stats.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(stats, f, indent=4))

log_data = {}

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if any(x in message.content.lower() for x in ["bye", "cya", "bb", "gn8", "cya later"]):
        await loging.meslog_green(bot, message, 'bye')
        log_data = load_stats()
        authorid = str(message.author.id)
        author = str(message.author)
        if authorid {'bye'} in log_data:
            log_data[str(message.author.id)]['bye'] += 1
            save_stats(log_data)
        else:
            log_data[str(message.author.id)] = {}
            log_data[str(message.author.id)]['bye'] = 1
            save_stats(log_data)
    
    if any(x in message.content.lower() for x in ["hello", "hey", "hi", "greetings", "good morning", "good afternoon"]):
        await loging.meslog_green(bot, message, 'hey')
        log_data = load_stats()
        authorid = str(message.author.id)
        author = str(message.author)
        if authorid {'hey'} in log_data:
            log_data[str(message.author.id)]['hey'] += 1
            save_stats(log_data)
        else:
            log_data[str(message.author.id)] = {}
            log_data[str(message.author.id)]['hey'] = 1
            save_stats(log_data)

@bot.command(name='hey')
async def hey(ctx):
    stats = load_stats()
    await ctx.reply(f'you said {stats[ctx.author.id]["hey"]} times stats ', delete_after=10.0)'
    await loging.comlog_green(bot, ctx, 'hey')
```

**the stats.json :**

```
{
    "448827301235084672": {
        "hey": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: You're currently hardcoding the word "hey" in there. Instead, loop over the list of all words you want to include, check if any of them are in the message, and add them to the file if they are.

Comment: can you give more information about this?
although it is very easy for persons who are expirencet, i am very new and would love to learn how to do it right rather than trying unsuccessfully!

Comment: Right now you're adding the counter to `["hey"]` manually in your code, which means you're never gonna increment the counter for any of the other words. By looping over the list of words, and storing the current word in a variable, you can set the counter of a random word based on that variable. If that is too complex I suggest you look into basic loops & dictionaries in Python first (discord bots aren't exactly beginner-friendly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpreted your question correctly and you only need to format your file better, you can use the `indent` option.

> If `indent` is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and
> object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent
> level of 0 will only insert newlines. `None` is the most compact
> representation.

For example, using

```py
def save_stats(stats):
    with open('stats.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(stats, f, indent=4)
```

will result in

```json
{
    "448827123485084672": {
        "hey": 2
    },
    "884530123033089076": {
        "hey": 1
    }
}
```

You don't need to modify the load method because the indent doesn't actually change the meaning of the json data.

Comment: this already help me with 50% of my problem ^^ tyvm 
could you help me read those data with a command ?
iam having really problems with that one :S

Comment: What do you mean by read the data with a command? Would it be `json_stuff[str(SOME_USER.id)] -> {"hey": 2}`?

Comment: yea , thats would be it.

Comment: also i have still a problem saving multiple counter

Comment: What do you mean by saving multiple counter? I think the comment would be helpful. You can make a function called `increment(user, key)` that increments a key such as `"hey"` by 1, and then that would clean up the code as well as make it easier to add more triggers if you ever need.

Comment: with multiple counter i mean i save under the same userid things like , hey = 2 , bye = 4 , thanks = 2 , please = 3. you know any example of increments in use or a documentation i can read in ?

Comment: Then you should do as the comment mentioned, or you can adapt it like how you use the line `if any(x in message.content.lower() for x in ["hello", "hey", "hi", "greetings", "good morning", "good afternoon"]):`, and you can change it to something like `if any(x in message.content.lower() for x in ["thanks", "thank you"])` , etc. You have the right idea - just change the value changed: something like `log_data[str(message.author.id)]['thanks'] += 1`.

Comment: if i do it like this ,i got already `{"448827301485084672": {"hey": 1}}` in my stats.json
and write bye , ill get `log_data[str(message.author.id)]['bye'] += 1
KeyError: 'bye`

Comment: If the key doesn't exist you'll need to make it first: `if 'STRING' not in log_data[id]: log_data[id]['STRING'] = 0`. Also you have this line in your original code: `if authorid {'hey'} in log_data:` which shouldn't be proper syntax. Instead, at the top, populate it with an empty dictionary if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: tyvm for you help , i hope this wasnt too annoying , i guess with the knowledge gathered i will be manage to make the command for userid stats by my own. i saw you helped me with my other questions few days ago too , have not just a great day/night , i wish you a great week .  ^^